# CSS Loses Properties after PHP Code?

Tags: php, html, css, properties

This has been bugging me... I'm making a new search bar form my website, and I've encountered a few bugs.

My bar usually looks like this:

[image]

And when I add the code in order to make the form submit, this happens:

[image]

My search bar looks normal with this code:

```
<link href="default/search.css" rel="stylesheet" title="Style" />
<form class="form-wrapper">
    <input type="text" name="keyname" id="search" placeholder="Search" required>
    <input type="submit" value="Search" id="submit">

</form>
```

But gets deformed as soon as I make it like this:

```
<form action="results.php" method="get">
<link href="default/search.css" rel="stylesheet" title="Style" />
<form class="form-wrapper">
    <input type="text" name="keyname" id="search" placeholder="Search" required>
    <input type="submit" value="Search" id="submit">

</form>
```

If you need to see the css code for my search bar, here it is. pastebin.com/92MvMS3m

Why does this happen? And how do I prevent it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `<form action="results.php" method="get">`

Change

```
<form class="form-wrapper">
```

To

```
<form class="form-wrapper" action="results.php" method="get">
```

Answer (score 0):

Move css link into inside the `head` tag

```
 <link href="default/search.css" rel="stylesheet" title="Style" />
```

Form: Merge two form tags into one as like below

```
 <form action="results.php" method="get" class="form-wrapper">
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have two `<form>` tags for one form?

```
<form action="results.php" method="get">
<link href="default/search.css" rel="stylesheet" title="Style" />
<form class="form-wrapper">
```

It should be this; note the `<form>` tag before the CSS is removed but the `action` and `method` were added to the one that shows up after the CSS tag:

```
<link href="default/search.css" rel="stylesheet" title="Style" />
<form class="form-wrapper" action="results.php" method="get">
```